# Why cant I reassign this variable to a new value in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I know the selection sort algorithm is not correct. That's fine for now, but why
can I not assign iMinimum to j inside the j for loop??
I'm using node version 10+. The console.log "iMinimum is now … " shows the value of the variable assigned earlier above, so I'm confused.

```
 console.log('SELECTION SORT')

let data = [5,1,3,9,4]

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 iMinimum = i


for(let j = iMinimum+1; j < data.length; j++){
     console.log(`j is now ${j}`)
     if(data[j] < data[iMinimum]){
         iMininum = j
         console.log(`iMinimum is now ${iMinimum} and j is ${j}`)
     }
}
data[i] = data[iMinimum] 
}

console.log(`Sorted Array: ${data}`)
```

Comment: typo iMini`n`um vs iMini`m`um

Comment: omgggg thanks i thought the interpreter would give me an undefined error. Why didn't it??

Comment: @Prasanna tagged

Comment: You are declaring an entirely new variable there. just like you did above with `iMinimum = i`.

Comment: @Prasanna thanks … time for me to tell people to delete this question lol

Comment: We have all been there. Sometimes it is frustrating as hell. Don't worry, you are doing great!

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos, note `iMininum` vs `iMinimum`.

To let the interpreter warn you of undeclared variables, start your file with

```
'use strict';
```

This will enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), forcing you to declare all variables.

For further analysis, run a linter, such as [`eslint`](https://eslint.org/). This will automatically detect your problems:

```
   7:5   error  'iMinimum' is not defined                       no-undef
   8:17  error  'iMinimum' is not defined                       no-undef
  10:28  error  'iMinimum' is not defined                       no-undef
  11:14  error  'iMininum' is not defined                       no-undef
  12:45  error  'iMinimum' is not defined                       no-undef
  15:20  error  'iMinimum' is not defined                       no-undef
```